# building problem in simple_arm_server in fuerte

Tags: ros, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm using ros fuerte...when i did rosmake in the simple_arms it gives the error like this...

### [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/simple_move_arm_server.dir/src/simple_move_arm_server.o
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src/simple_move_arm_server.cpp: In member function ‘void SimpleArmNavigationServer::goalCB()’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src/simple_move_arm_server.cpp:147: error: ‘class btMatrix3x3’ has no member named ‘getRPY’
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src/simple_move_arm_server.cpp:187: error: ‘class btQuaternion’ has no member named ‘setRPY’
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple_move_arm_server.dir/src/simple_move_arm_server.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple_move_arm_server.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package simple_arm_server written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/rajan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130319-122743/simple_arm_server/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< simple_arm_server [FAIL] [ 4.82 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package simple_arm_server.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 71 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/rajan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130319-122743

when i tried to build the pkg simple_arm_server then it is giving the error....

[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/simple_move_arm_server.dir/src/simple_move_arm_server.o
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src/simple_move_arm_server.cpp: In member function ‘void SimpleArmNavigationServer::goalCB()’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src/simple_move_arm_server.cpp:147: error: ‘class btMatrix3x3’ has no member named ‘getRPY’
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/src/simple_move_arm_server.cpp:187: error: ‘class btQuaternion’ has no member named ‘setRPY’
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple_move_arm_server.dir/src/simple_move_arm_server.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple_move_arm_server.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simple_arms/simple_arm_server/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2

plzzz help me out as soon as possible....thanx in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58499/building-problem-in-simple_arm_server-in-fuerte/) by [rajan_seeker](https://answers.ros.org/users/4463/rajan_seeker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

WHy are you building in /opt/ros/fuerte? If you installed from debs, then the package is already built. If you did a source checkout, you should not do it into /opt/ros.

simple_arms is building under Fuerte on the build farm, so I don't think there is currently anything broken in the repo. Where did you check your source out from?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajan_seeker](https://answers.ros.org/users/4463/rajan_seeker/) on 2013-03-18**:
svn https://vanadium-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simple_arms

**Comment by [rajan_seeker](https://answers.ros.org/users/4463/rajan_seeker/) on 2013-03-18**:
i ve install simple_arms from this link